# Sharepoint 2013 Wiki history page always shows the first word as added

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

When I change a word from wiki page, wiki history page shows first word as added. Although I not change the first word

this error always occurs on the first word of the page.

Comment: check image https://ibb.co/KjZF9PT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My test result is the same as yours, and the same behaviour in SharePoint Online.

So this should be by design.  It is indeed a very strange behaviour but basically does not affect the use.

Comment: Thanks for your information. I surprised that there is same behavior in SharePoint Online